# TYPO3 RTE Allow Bold to be used in H tags

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, rte

I am using TYPO3 7.6 and in the RTE I need to be able to use the bold button to add `<strong>`inside the H tags. Is there a way in the page TS Config to allow this?

I can't find anything about it in the docs...

Comment: Is the `strong` tag correctly outputted and only the styling is wrong or is the `strong` tag not visible in the HTML at all?

Comment: @GhostGambler The tag doesn't get added to the RTE html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you can't make an H tag bold, but that it's already bold by default. If you add CSS to the RTE to make the `font-weight` of H tags `normal` it should work. You can add a custom CSS file to the RTE by adding the following to your Page TSconfig:

```
RTE.default {
  contentCSS = path/to/css/file.css
}
```

Comment: Some of my h tags are not bold by default already but I need one word to be bolded in some cases. The rte stylesheet cannot be added because of some glitch I am not able to fix unfortunately. If it requires the rte css to be there then I have a problem...